# GRANT Database Scoped Credential syntax gives mismatched input error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-purview

I am working on this MS Azure article: [Connect to and manage Azure Synapse Analytics workspaces in Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-synapse-workspace). But in [Grant permission to use credentials for external tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-synapse-workspace#grant-permission-to-use-credentials-for-external-tables) section of the article, when I run the following query, I get the error shown below:

**SQL**:
GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[mySynapseWorkspace] TO [myPurviewAccountName];

**Error**:

> mismatched input 'SCOPED' expecting ':'

**Question**: What may be a cause of the error, and how can we fix it?

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70527568/15969417

Answer (score 1):

I learn from a similar issue logged that you should be providing your credential name and username instead.

Try,

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[your_credential_name] TO [your_username];
```

Comment: According to article I referenced, the `your_username` is `myPurviewAccountName`. What would be the `your_credential_name` here?

Comment: the scoped credential i.e. the one used in account credential

Comment: Which account? Could you please give me an example that may help me.

Comment: `your_username` is the LOGIN name you created first from the external provider and `your_credential_name`  from [Create a new credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/manage-credentials#create-a-new-credential)